# Is it possible to JSON.deserializeUntyped directly to DateTime without information about field is DateTime?

Tags: apex, json, datetime, deserialize

I wonder if it is possible to JSON.deserializeUntyped directly to DateTime type. 
How can I check if deserialized Object in Map has type of DateTime? I am curious  is it possible, because Object in map has always String type.

```
String myDate = '{ "MyDate" : "2018-08-31T06:00:00.000Z" }';
Map<String, Object> ds = (Map<String, Object>) 
JSON.deserializeUntyped(myDate);
System.debug(ds.get('MyDate') instanceof DateTime);
System.debug(JSON.deserialize((String)ds.get('MyDate'), DateTime.class));
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format doesn't line up with those that work with `Datetime.valueOf` (nor `Datetime.parse`). The format it expects is `2018-08-31 06:00:00` I was able to do some light string manipulation to get the `Datetime` value:

```
String myDate = '{"MyDate": "2018-08-31T06:00:00.000Z"}';
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(myDate);
String formatted = ((String)data.get('MyDate')).replace('T', ' ').replace('.000Z', '');
Datetime value = Datetime.valueOfGmt(formatted));
```

Answer (score 4):

No, deserializedUntyped simply doesn't work that way; it can only deserialize to `List<Object>`, `Map<String, Object>`, `Decimal`, `String`, `Boolean` and `null`. It doesn't try to figure out if there's a `Date` or a `DateTime` or a more complicated structure. However, assuming you have your value, you can parse it independently:

```
Map<String, Object> values = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(myDate);
String value = (String)values.get('MyDate');
DateTime dt = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"'+value+'"', DateTime.class);
```

I realize it's not terribly practical, but that's the only way you'd get the JSON parser to work the way you'd like. It'd be far more practical to JSON.deserialize to a concrete data type:

```
Map<String, DateTime> values = (Map<String, DateTime>)
  JSON.deserialize(myDate, Map<String, DateTime>.class);
```

Or, as Adrian suggested, removing the parts that DateTime.valueOf/DateTime.parse don't like, and using that instead.